# How to set position of MediaElement?

Tags: c#, position, set, mediaelement

I have this button:

```
private void Answer1_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MediaElement1.Play();
}
```

The problem is that if I click it and then quickly click it again the sound will just continue to play from the position it was when I pressed it again.

What I want is to make the sound replay from the start `0,0`.
So I thought I may could do it by maybe setting the sound position to `0,0` in the button in the previous line of `MediaElement1.Play();`.

If you know any better solution is good too ;)

Comment: Take a look at [MSDN: MediaElement.Position Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.position(v=vs.110).aspx) i googled that in 2 seconds.

Comment: Ye I agree, but it's not that clear there for me...
Thanks though ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just set the [`Position`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.position%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
MediaElement1.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
MediaElement1.Play();
```